# The data inserted into the MySQL is truncated

Tags: mysql

I have a large piece of data to insert into the database，but the data inserted into the MySQL is truncated.

**I checked the log file record of MySQL, the sql is correct**, 
like this “INSERT into record set aaa = 'long long long text'”.

But the 'aaa' in mysql is truncated.

Column type is longtext.

The original data length is 197917, and the length of the data in mysql is 83949

Server is nodejs, and using mysql npm package.

I'm curious about the difference between the sql of the mysql log file and the actual running sql...

Thank you all.

Comment: What is the data type of that column?

Comment: What is the data type? Did you set a maximum amount of characters on that column? Any mysql triggers? What is the exact input in your query (is it really long long long text or did you just use it as an example?)?

Comment: column type is longtext;

Comment: it is really long long text, and the whole sql in mysql log file is correct, when i run with command line using this sql, it can correctly insert whole data into mysql.